# Getting "TypeError: '' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type." very sporadically on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, web-applications, safari

Been developing a vanilla javascript PWA with firebase for some time now and have for the last few months encountered this weird scenario:

The web app is added to the home screen of an IOS device and has been working fine for weeks when all of a sudden it opens to a completely white screen or (in rare cases) to our custom page load animation which never closes. Closing the app and relaunching it from the home screen does nothing and opening the app in safari itself produces the same result. The only fix is to remove the app from the home screen, clearing the safari cache and re-adding to home screen. This only happens on IOS devices and very sporadically (roughly once a month or two, although it´s been happening more frequently as of this month). We've never encountered the error on any other browser or operating system.

Since the error is so infrequent and "random" debugging is a pain. The only real clue I have is this type error:

```
TypeError: '' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
[N]promiseReactionJob
```

[Logs from an iPhone encountering the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hRB.jpg).

I'm completely lost here and any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if I'm not mistaken by opening that page you send a request to the backend to do something and there you defined ```json/application``` or something like this. If this is the case you must change that part of the code to accept the right type coming from your frontend.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but if returning requested scripts was the problem, why would it happen so sporadically do you think?

Comment: I was facing the same problem and found out that by clicking on a button I'm sending a ```POST``` request where I defined a method with this ```json/application``` type and in response I was sending ```b64``` image which was not the same type as I defined it so it ```throw``` an error like that. In your case there must be something like that but I don't have the backend or the part of code to say it for sure

Comment: Ok, the only requests on startup are the HTML, CSS and JavaScript files from a CDN. The weird thing is that if the CDN was consistently returning files of wrong type the error wouldn't happen so rarely. The error disappears if the safari cache is cleared so I'm thinking it might have something to do with returned cached files.

Comment: could you put those static files on your local and read them from there

Comment: Don't know how I would go about that on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. Explicitly adding the parent directory of the offending files to the initial `cache.addAll` call in the "install" event. Seems to have solved it. E.g. One offending file was being served from `<domain>/js/OFFENDING_FILE.js`. I had only `'/'` in the `cache.addAll` array. Adding `'/js'` to the `cache.addAll` array appears to have solved this issue.